# Custom tableview automatically generated by UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I need to have access to the tableview instance which is automatically generated when there is more than 5 tabbars (where tabBarItem "more" appears) in the main class that extends UITabeBarController. I would like to slightly customize the tableview how to remove the separator lines (`tableView.separatorStyle = .none`).

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you want to remove separator line from table view?

Comment: Yes, to conform to the design of other screens of my application. The problem is that I do not know how I have access to the instance of this tableview that is automatically generated by the UITabBarController when there are more than 5 ViewControllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift

```
    let tab = UITabBarController()
    if let viewController = tab.moreNavigationController.viewControllers.first as? UIViewController, let tableview = viewController.view as? UITableView {
        tableview.separatorStyle = .none
    }
```

ObjC

```
    UITabBarController *tab = [UITabBarController new];
    UIViewController *vc = [tab.moreNavigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
    if ([vc.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        [(UITableView *)vc.view setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested, but it did not work. I have a class called MainController that extends UITabBarController and associated it with View in the Storyboard. As shown in the image I added.

Comment: In your case, you will have to put in that instance of the MainController instead of 'tab' specified in the given code. Can you confirm you did like that? I just created an instance of UITabBarController to show how its done. Also it must be made sure that the tabbarController instance (MainTabbar in your case) has already loaded all the view controllers.

Comment: I understood what the problem was, I was not able to convert the `self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers.first` to `UITableViewController`. So I did the following: `if let tableviewController = self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers.first, let tableview = tableviewController.view as? UITableView {
            tableview.separatorStyle = .none
        }`. Now it worked. Thanks a lot for the help. Thankful.

Comment: Yes, casting as a UIViewController and checking for the view to be a UITableview is a better bet. (y)